# Laravel en producción no carga relaciona vista y lógica

Tags: php, laravel, blade, componentes

Tengo un proyecto en laravel, el cual está subido a un servidor con plesk. Utilizo laravel toolkit para las diferentes funciones del proyecto.

El problema radica en que los componentes que tengo (navbar, aside...) no pasan por su lógica para obtener las variables ni renderizar, simplemente me muestran lo que aparece en el resources/views/componente.blade.php.

esto es la lógica del alert, por ejemplo, en el app/View/Componentes/alert.php:

```
namespace App\View\Components;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class alert extends Component
{
    public $type;
    public $text;
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     */
    public function __construct($type,$text)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     */
    public function render(): View|Closure|string
    {
        return view('components.alert');
    }
}
```

y esto el componente en resources/views/components/alert.blade.php

````
    const Toast = Swal.mixin({
  toast: true,
  position: 'top-end',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  showCloseButton: true,
  timer: 3000,
  timerProgressBar: true,
  didOpen: (toast) => {
    toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
    toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
  }
})
Toast.fire({
  icon: '{{ $type }}',
  title: '{{ $text }}',
})
</script>```

El tema es que me muestra el script sin variables.
````

Comment: y en local si te funciona???

Answer (score 0):

Al final el problema era el tema de las mayúsculas en la nomenclatura de los componentes. Resulta que en local, el componente lo escribo en minúscula y no pasa nada, pero en producción exigía Pascal Case.